# Do I have to specify the partition key and all clustering keys in every query?

Tags: cassandra, cql

For example, if my primary key is `a` and clustering columns are `b` and `c`.

Can I only use the following in where condition?

```
select * from table where a = 1 and b = 2 and c = 3
```

Or are there any other queries that I can use?

I want to use

```
select * from table where a=1
```

and

```
select * from table where a = 1 and b = 2 and c = 3 and d = 4
```

Is that possible?

If not, then how can I model my data to make this possible?

Comment: While I understand the title to the question is opinion based, the actual question asked is based on which columns can be used to query data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cassandra has lots of advantages, but it does not fit for every need.

Cassandra is a good choice, when you need to *handle large amount of writes*. People like it, because Cassandra is easily scalable, *can handle huge datasets* and *highly fault tolerant*.

You need to keep in mind that with Cassandra (if you really want to utilize it) the basic rule is to model your data to fit your queries. Don't model around relations. Don't model around objects. **Model around your queries.** This way you can minimize partition reads.

And of course you can query not just the primary keys and partition columns. You can:

- add [secondary index](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.3/cql/cql_using/useSecondaryIndex.html) to some columns or
- use the [ALLOW FILTERING](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/allow-filtering-explained-2) keyword

but of course, these are not   that effective as having a well-modeled table.

Answer (score 0):

> For example, if my primary key is a and clustering columns are b and c.

So this translates into a definition of: `PRIMARY KEY ((a),b,c)`.  Based on that...

> are there any other queries that I can use?

Yes.  Some important points to understand; is that the query's WHERE clause with PRIMARY KEYs:

- Must be specified in order.
- Cannot be skipped.
- Can be omitted, as long as the keys prior to it are specified.

`select * from table where a=1`

Yes, this query will work.  That's because you're still querying by your partition key (`a`).

`select * from table where a = 1 and b = 2 and c = 3 and d = 4`

However, this will ***not*** work.  That is because `d` is not (based on my understanding of your first statement) a part of your PRIMARY KEY definition.

> If not, then how can I model my data to make this possible?

As Andrea mentioned, you should build your table according to the queries it needs to support.  So if you need to query by `a`, `b`, `c`, *and* `d`, you'll need to make `d` a part of your PRIMARY KEY.